# Can variables in Javascript not be declared in time

Tags: javascript

I have been learning the asynchronous nature of Javascript, and I understand that certain functions take a certain amount of time to complete.

For instance, I'll create a promise when I want to do something when a file operation is complete.

Declaring variables with different data types don't need to be in a promise, but I was wondering if it is possible for a normal variable to not be declared in time when it is later referenced? I understand that they are near-instant, and it is never a problem, but I would like some insight on how this is handled in the interpreter.

Comment: Can you show an example? Keep in mind that promises never run functions passed to `.then()` (for example) immediately/synchronously, even if the promise not only resolves quickly but is *already resolved before you call it*. Execution never stops in the middle of code that’s running synchronously, either. It’s single-threaded with no preemption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some actions do take some time to complete, but *almost all* Javascript code is completely synchronous. That is, if you do something on line 1 (run a function, assign to a variable, create a variable), that will have completed by the time line 2 runs, *except* when the action taken spawns an asynchronous process (like a network request or a check for the existence of a file on the system).

Unless you're dealing with one of the few asynchronous processes, it won't be an issue. For similar reasons:

```
let num = 1;
num++;
console.log(num);
```

is guaranteed to print `2`.

Initializing a variable is not asynchronous, so it *will* be declared in time, as long as you declare it *before* you try to reference it.

If you try to reference a variable declared with `var` before the line where it's declared, you'll get `undefined` (an error won't be thrown, but the variable won't contain anything):

```js
(() => {
  console.log(foo);
  var foo = 5;
})();
```

If you try to reference a variable declared with `let` or `const` before the line where it's declared, a ReferenceError will be thrown:

```js
(() => {
  console.log(foo);
  let foo = 5;
})();
```

But these errors are easily avoidable simply by looking at the order of the lines in your code.